# How to center a button with a custom width using autolayout constraints?

Tags: ios6, autolayout, rubymotion, nslayoutconstraint, visual-format-language

Please see the following code:

```
def viewDidLoad
    super
    self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor

    @start = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonTypeRoundedRect).tap do |el|
      el.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false          
      el.setTitle('Start', forState:UIControlStateNormal)
      el.addTarget(self, action:'toStartController', forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside)
      self.view.addSubview(el)
    end

    self.layout_subviews
  end

def layout_subviews
    metrics = { 'space' => 8 }

    views_dict = { 
      'superview' => self.view, 
      'start' => @start
    }

    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat('H:|-[start(100)]-|', 
                                                                    options: NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX, 
                                                                    metrics: metrics, 
                                                                      views: views_dict))

    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat('V:[start]-|', 
                                                                    options: NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom, 
                                                                    metrics: metrics, 
                                                                      views: views_dict))
  end
```

The problem I'm having is `H:|-[start(100)]-|` won't work. What I want is a button with a width of 100 centered on the X-axis and attached to the bottom of the screen with a default margin. As soon as I remove the `(100)` this works, however the button stretches to the width of the screen minus the default margins. When I specify a custom width I reckon the Auto Layout system can't work out what the left and right margins should be. I get an `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.` error. I guess this has something to do with the dashes in `H:|-[start(100)]-|`, which need to have a fluid width to attach the `start` element to the `superview`, instead of being the default margins.

Any thoughts on how I might solve this?

**Update (thanks ghettopia):**

*This works (notice I'm using a `UINavigationController` in the app delegate and `self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` in `viewDidLoad` of `TestController` is commented out):*

```
class AppDelegate
  def application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
    @window = UIWindow.alloc.initWithFrame(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds).tap do |win|
      controller = TestController.alloc.initWithNibName(nil, bundle:nil)
      win.rootViewController = UINavigationController.alloc.initWithRootViewController(controller).tap do |root|
        root.navigationBarHidden = true
        root.wantsFullScreenLayout = true
      end
      win.makeKeyAndVisible
    end
    true
  end
end

class TestController < UIViewController

  def viewDidLoad
    super
    # self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor

    @button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonTypeRoundedRect)
    @button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(@button)

    views = { 
      'view' => self.view, 
      'button' => @button
    }

    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat('H:[button(100)]', options: 0, metrics: nil, views: views))
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintWithItem(@button, attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat('V:[button]-|', options: 0, metrics: nil, views: views))
  end
end
```

[image: Correct screen]

*Great. Now I get a blue screen with a button centered on the X-axis with a default margin to the bottom, just as I intended. However, from what I've read `self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` is required to make Auto Layout work. To make that happen, this works as well (notice I'm not using a `UINavigationController` this time and `self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` in `viewDidLoad` of `TestController` IS being used):*

```
class AppDelegate
  def application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
    @window = UIWindow.alloc.initWithFrame(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds).tap do |win|
      win.rootViewController = TestController.alloc.initWithNibName(nil, bundle:nil)
      win.makeKeyAndVisible
    end
    true
  end
end

class TestController < UIViewController

  def viewDidLoad
    super
    self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor

    @button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonTypeRoundedRect)
    @button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(@button)

    views = { 
      'view' => self.view, 
      'button' => @button
    }

    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat('H:[button(100)]', options: 0, metrics: nil, views: views))
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintWithItem(@button, attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat('V:[button]-|', options: 0, metrics: nil, views: views))
  end
end
```

But that doesn't seem like a proper solution. I need a `UINavigationController` to create my app structure. The thing is when I don't use any of the above solutions I get a black screen with a button dead in the middle (on both axis). The views seems to be broken:
[image: Black screen]

Thoughts? Should I just remove `self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` and forget about it or is it indeed required? If it is, there must be something wrong with my code.

**Update 2:**

Interesting tutorial: [Auto Layout in iOS 6: Adding constraints through code](http://ioscreator.com/auto-layout-in-ios-6-adding-constraints-through-code/). The author doesn't use `self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` in `viewDidLoad`, only on subviews.

**Update 3:**

I think I may have solved the black screen problem by moving `self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` to the `init` method instead of `viewDidLoad`. Not sure why this works though, but the screen looks identical to the screenshot now, just as I intented in the first place. Here's the updated code:

```
class AppDelegate
  def application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
    @window = UIWindow.alloc.initWithFrame(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds).tap do |win|
      controller = TestController.alloc.initWithNibName(nil, bundle:nil)
      win.rootViewController = UINavigationController.alloc.initWithRootViewController(controller).tap do |root|
        root.navigationBarHidden = true
        root.wantsFullScreenLayout = true
      end
      win.makeKeyAndVisible
    end
    true
  end
end    

class TestController < UIViewController

  def init
    self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  end

  def viewDidLoad
    super
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor

    @button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonTypeRoundedRect)
    @button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(@button)

    views = { 
      'view' => self.view, 
      'button' => @button
    }

    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat('H:[button(100)]', options: 0, metrics: nil, views: views))
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintWithItem(@button, attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat('V:[button]-|', options: 0, metrics: nil, views: views))
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] ;
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO ;
[self.view addSubview:button] ;

NSDictionary* views = @{ @"view" : self.view  ,  @"button" : button } ;
// Make button's width 100.
[self.view addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[button(100)]"  options:0   metrics:nil  views:views ] ] ;
// Make button's CenterX the same as self.view's CenterX.
[self.view addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual  toItem:self.view  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX  multiplier:1  constant:0 ] ] ;
// Make button's NSLayoutAttributeBottom the default space away from self.view's NSLayoutAttributeBottom.
[self.view addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[button]-|"  options:0   metrics:nil  views:views ] ] ;
```

Comment: I hope this answer helps. I know it's a little late, but I just came across your question.

Comment: Your code works, but there's another problem I'm running into. In the app delegate I use a `rootViewController` on the window object with a `UINavigationController` which inits another controller containing the code above. If I run the code, the background stays black and the botton is centered in the middle (on both axis). But when I remove the 'self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;` line in `viewDidLoad` of the corresponding `UIViewController`, the code works. But isn't this line supposed to be present?

Comment: Another solutions seems to be to set the `rootViewController` of the window object directly to the corresponding `UIViewController` instead of using the `UINavigationController` and leave the line `self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;` in `viewDidLoad` intact. Now the code works as well. But that doesn't seem right as a `UINavigationController` is required to build an app structure.

Comment: The WWDC 2012 session video [Best Practices for Mastering Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=228) (starting at 11:40) advises `setTranslatesAutoresizingMarkIntoConstraints:NO` for programmatically-created views.
Sorry, I don't know enough about View Controllers to help you with the rest of your question. Maybe posting screenshots would attract new answers.

Comment: That's what I understood from the WWDC 2012 session videos as well. They mentioned this line should always be present or Auto Layout might behave erratically. Strangely enough that line is precisely what is causing problems in my code. I've added screenshots. Anyway, because you have answered my initial question I will accept your answer. Hopefully others will clarify my issue with the black screen. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the accept, but others may see the accepted answer and think your problem is completely solved.

Comment: True, I'm not sure whether I should post a new question or leave it here. It seems to be a fundamental issue with Auto Layout instead of with the constraints themselves. I seem to be doing everything by the book though, it's weird.

Comment: I seem to have found a solution by moving the line to the `init` method. Does this make sense?